# I want to be able to say, "Hey Google, Create a meeting on TestApp" is this possible without opening the application

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am working on a project to integrate the Google Assistant with an existing Android app. The requirements are simple. Assuming my app is named TestApp and I want it to just Create a meeting, I want to be able to say, "Hey Google, Create a meeting on TestApp".

The closest API I found that does what I need is the Voice Interactions. This is very similar to what I need done but it only allows preset voice triggers such as "call this person..." or "set alarm at...", but cannot do "create a task or something else..." like in my example. According to this link, custom voice actions aren't allowed.

So my question is, is it possible to directly interact with my app and have it do a very simple task?

Comment: if a user tells to the google assistant to create meeting without going inside the app the app should respond him

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No, not directly. But your Action can be made to prompt the user for permission to "deep-link" into an Android activity. To do that you need first to associate the Action and the Activity in the console. Sample code is here

https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_helper.deeplink.html

Longer Answer: Before there were Actions on Google there were Google Now Actions. (Yeah I know it's confusing). With Google Now Actions the Google App on a phone can be made to launch an Android activity with an intent which carries search terms in the bundle of "string extras". Then your user would say something like

"OK, Google search for the meeting creator on TestApp". Then you would get the text "the meeting creator" as a query string extra in a specially crafted search intent which launches TestApp into its meeting-creating activity. Details are here:

https://www.seroundtable.com/google-now-actions-19436.html

Unlike Actions on Google, Google Now Actions forces your user to pose his request as a search.